# Create wordpress post via webhook and populate ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently using a webhook via Gravity Forms to create a post in another WordPress instance via Zapier through to WP Webhooks. I can create the post, populate the content, publish status, author etc. perfectly, however, I can't seem to populate the custom fields within the post.

When mapping the ACF field names into the webhook no data is passed across. Has anyone had any experience of this and have an example of this working?

I have tried using both the ACF field names as the arguments and also targeting all of the field names with the argument being acf_meta_update.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/